# Little to no reaction in my hot process soap

Tags: process-chemistry

I tried to make hot process soap and it was a failure. I carefully weighed the ingredients, but when I added the KOH to the melted oil, nothing happened. When I watch videos on hot process soap making, the oil turns cloudy immediately when the alkali is added. In my case there was no color change and the oil remained clear.

I heated the mixture for over 2 hours at around 180F and got very little reaction. There was some slight coagulation of small white beads on the surface of the oil, but that was it. In videos it shows the oil turning into a mashed potato consistency in as little as 20 minutes. That did not happen in my case at all.

It was though my alkali component was grossly deficient. However, I followed the measures carefully. The formula I used was coconut oil, 5.6 ounces, palm oil 8 ounces, moringa oil 2.4 ounces, water 6.08 ounces, KOH 3.49 ounces. The KOH was in flake form. The package reads caustic potash, 93% purity, KOH.

Could the 93% purity have been the problem?

Another issue is possible water absorption by the KOH. I put some of it in the microwave and it quickly formed quite a puddle, which I mistakenly thought was molten KOH, but it must have been water on second thought, so it is possible the KOH had a high water content.

Comment: KOH certainly absorbs water. Some labs use it as a drying agent

Comment: Did you stir ? Your mixture must be stirred as much as possible, specially in the beginning, because oil and KOH solution are not miscible. The reaction starts at the contact surfaces of the two phases. After a while an emulsion is produced and it is less important to stir. The proportion of watering KOH is not the main parameter.

Comment: I agree, stirring is crucial

Comment: How old is the KOH? If not cared for appropriately or if there's a loose lid, over time you get potassium hydrogencarbonate.  It's not clear how you mixed the KOH and the oil.